# Why my image is not fully painted?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I have created Card class that extends JComponent.I'm not using any kind of layout. But when I add my card to the JFrame in spesific location using setBounds() method, the image cuts off, like this :
[image]

The paint Card method:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    if(degrees!=0) g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees));
    int first,second;
    switch(colorCardType){
    case RED_HEART: first = 0;
        break;
    case RED_DIAMOND: first = 1;
        break;
    case BLACK_SPADE: first = 2;
        break;
    case BLACK_CLUB: first = 3;
        break;
    default: first = 4;
        break;
    }
    switch(cardType) {
    case ACE: second = 0;
        break;
    case TWO: second = 1;
        break;
    case THREE: second = 2;
        break;
    case FOUR: second = 3;
        break;
    case FIVE: second = 4 ;
        break;
    case SIX: second = 5;
        break;
    case SEVEN: second = 6 ;
        break;
    case EIGHT: second = 7;
        break;
    case NINE: second =8 ;
        break;
    case TEN: second = 9;
        break;
    case JACK: second = 10;
        break;
    case QUEEN: second = 11;
        break;
    case KING: second = 12;
        break;
    default: second = 0;
        break;
    }
    g2d.drawImage(images[first][second], super.getX(), super.getY(), null);
}
```

The main Code: (the importmant part)

```
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(null);
Card test = new Card(CardType.ACE,ColorCardType.RED_HEART,0);
frame.add(test);
test.setBounds(40,0,72,96);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a paint method, coordinates are relative to the component itself.  Replace `super.getX(), super.getY()` with coordinates relative to the component itself;  the upper-left corner, for example, is `0, 0`.

Since you want to be able to rotate the image, you'll need to make the component as large as the image's diagonal length, √(72<sup>2</sup> + 96<sup>2</sup>), or 120 by 120 pixels.

Finally, you'll want to draw the card relative to the center of the component.  Before your `g2d.rotate`, add this to change the drawing origin to the center of the component:

```
g2d.translate(getWidth() / 2.0, getHeight() / 2.0);
```

Then change the drawImage call to draw relative to the component's center:

```
g2d.drawImage(images[first][second], -(72 / 2), -(96 / 2), null);
```

Ideally, of course, the 72 and 96 should not be hard-coded and should be obtained from the size of the image itself (which is easy if the image is a BufferedImage, but not as easy otherwise).

Comment: Thank you, it works. But now when I'm trying to rotate it, the card cuts off again. [exemple](http://prntscr.com/5gmczg)

Comment: The one-argument Graphics2D.rotate method rotates about the origin, (0, 0).  You probably want to use the [three-argument rotate method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#rotate-double-double-double-), which rotates about whatever point you specify.  Try rotating around the component's center:  `g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), getWidth() / 2.0, getHeight() / 2.0)`

Comment: Your component's width and height should both be the card image's diagonal distance, rounded up.  Either have your component class override `getPreferredSize()` to return a Dimension with that width and height, or, since you are using a null layout, set the size of the component explicitly.

Comment: I did it before. Still have this problem.

Comment: What do you see if you change `test.setBounds(40,0,72,96)` to `test.setBounds(40,0,120,120)`?

Comment: Ah, you need to center the image when drawing it.  Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: WOW thank you very much! finnaly, it doesnt cut off.